# How to access properties from other view controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios6, properties, uiviewcontroller

I am using Xcode 4.6.1 to develop for iOS 6.

I have two view controllers: `viewController1` and `viewController2`. I am trying to access a property defined in `viewController1` in `viewController2` as follow (but it isn't working):

This is `viewController1.m`:

```
#import "viewController1.h"

@interface viewController1 ()

@property (nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer;

@end

@implementation viewController1

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    ...

    self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

    ...

    [self.videoPlayer play];

    ...
}
```

This is `viewController2.m`:

```
#import "viewController2.h"
#import "viewController1.h"

@interface viewController2 ()

@end

@implementation viewController2

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    viewController1 *thePlayer;
    [thePlayer.videoPlayer pause];

    //This is where I get an error:
    //Property 'videoPlayer' not found on object of type 'viewController1 *'
}
```

I have tried a lot of searching but I wasn't able to figure out what am I doing wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you displaying both VCs at the same time? Using a `navigationController`? Are you using storyboards?

Comment: How are your viewControllers connected? If you are using a segue to get from viewController1 to viewController 2 you can use prepareForSegue to pass the reference forward. Otherwise you could use a delegate.

Comment: I am using storyboards. `viewController2` is actually a popover which is displayed in `viewController1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your `videoPlayer` property defined in your `viewController1.m`, but you import `viewController1.h`.

Move `videoPlayer` to `viewController1.h`. DO NOT import `viewController1.m`.

Comment: Yes! This was the problem! Thanks a lot. Stupid newbie mistake. Works great now :)